Safe Creation Fails on Safe-Infrastructure but rest functionalities work (also no view of Smart contract interactions and swap tokens)
I set up the Safe-Infrastructure. I have my contracts deployed and followed the steps in Readme for Safe-Infrastructure. I am not able to create the Safe from the Web UI.
I was able to create a safe-account using protocol-kit from a custom script and then was able to perform multi-sig from the UI (the smart account was there on UI) but the creation fails.
How can I go about debugging this?

My network is not part of the latest release of safe-core-sdk's EIP3770 short-name registry (is merged but not in last month's release) https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/protocol-kit/src/utils/eip-3770/config.ts

My contracts are deployed for version 1.4.1. I've set the version in UI env as NEXT_PUBLIC_SAFE_VERSION=1.4.1 (in ui.env of Safe-infrastructure repo, it was 1.3.0 by default so if that version is being used to fetch contracts, it would fail. I had to specify this particularly since @safe-global/protocol-kit's DEFAULT_SAFE_VERSION is 1.3.0)


Also, I only see Send Tokens option when I create a transaction and not the options to build a smart contract transaction

How can I enable smart contract interactions?

Thanks a lot for your question.
The problem is that Safe{Wallet only supports Safes up to a version of 1.3.0. This is indicated in the Safe Infrastructure Installation Guide.
The next version of the Safe{Wallet} will support higher versions of Safe, but a release date is not scheduled.
For now, unfortunately, you have to deploy and use the Safe Singleton with version 1.3.0.

Thanks for responding. So I deployed all the smart-account contracts with 1.3.0 right now but the behaviour is the same (including smart contract interactions and token swap missing).
Could it be due to the release of safe-deployment not containing v1.3.0 contracts? I used the same singleton I used for 1.4.1, could that be a problem (although the addresses it gave were correct)

Good job! Exactly, to add your contracts to the official Safe{Wallet}, you have to follow these steps.
If you don't want to wait the time, you can run your own version of Safe{Wallet} if you want to give it a try.
